# jemmyFx, How to test FXML applications with two or more scens?

Tags: javafx-2, fxml, jemmyfx

I have FXML application with more than one scene. main method is on one Controller class and within that controller we load loginController. What i need to do is test this loginController UI. But there is no start method. I need to know how to pass scene changes while testing.

Comment: I got the issue.. In my case we need to wait some time to load the components. Then it automatically identify the components..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the issue.. In my case we need to wait some time to load the components. Then it automatically identify the components.. 
What i did is only check for one test case. But when i skip time using dummy loop and load the second test case. Then Jemmyfx identify my components in fxml file correctly.